# How to return null instead of empty array or empty object?

Tags: php, json

By default php json_encode() returns "[]" empty brackets for empty array. Also, it's possible to change to return "{}" brackets:

```
<?php

  $result = array();
  $json = json_encode($result, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
  print($json);
```

The thing is need to fix web services to return null instead of empty brackets if array if empty. Is there any easy and standard way?

Comment: one simple `if` condition doesn't seem easy enough for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I understand you would have deep nested structures and you want to replace empty leaves with null.

If that is the case you could simply find and replace.

```
$result = array("test" => array("Foo"=> new stdClass()), "testy" => array());
$json = json_encode($result);
$strippedJson = str_replace(array('[]', '{}'), 'null', $json);
```

Will give this json:

```
{"test":{"Foo":null},"testy":null}
```

Please note that it replaces empty leaves, but it does not replace branches only containing null leaves.

Answer (score 0):

can't you do this?:

```
print ($json == '[]') ? null : $json;
```

Comment: Webservices contain quite a big nested data structure, so a lot of manual checks would be needed.